# Table elements in Code behind using bootsrap overlap to the to div element

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Div like:

```
 <div  style="border:0px solid #ff0000;width:60%;margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class="div_container" style="width:100%;border:1px solid #ff0000;" id="div_dynamic_table" runat="server">
                    <%--<div class="box" style="border:1px solid #ff0000;"  runat="server">
                        <table id="id_dynamic_table" runat="server" class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    sample
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="txtuname2" type="text" id="txtuname2" class="form-control" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>--%>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my Code behind:

```
sbTable.Append("<table class='table'>");
            sbTable.Append("<tr><td style='white-space:nowrap'> sample Message td </ td>");
            sbTable.Append("<td> <input name='txtuname' type='text' id='txtuname' class='form-control' runat='server' /> </ td> ");
            sbTable.Append("</ tr>");
            sbTable.Append("</ table>");

            div_dynamic_table.InnerHtml = sbTable.ToString();
```

When i run the code it return a result:

[image]

I am expecting that the inputbox is inside the div only.

Otherwise if i uncomment the table in my html code its is working well and the inputbox get inside in the div.

The reason why i need the table creation in code behind is to run the table dynamically.

Additional information I am  using bootstrap.

Any Advise is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `style="width:100%"` to your `<input>` element?

Comment: @ObsidianAge: the Bootstrap class "form-control" has `width: 100%` and `display: block` in it.

Comment: @Vijunav It may not matter for this issue, but Bootstrap tables won't look quite right if you don't have a `<tbody>`. Maybe you should give that a try. My guess right now is that somehow the control is calculating 100% as being 100% of the page, not the wrapper `<div>` which has a width of 60%. Just roughly, it seems like your input is overlapping about the other 40%. You might also try wrapping your control in an `input-group`.

Comment: Thanks @Cory need to try it.

Comment: you can set width for your input element like  <input style="width:200px" >

Comment: Thanks to all the advise.

Comment: As i observed seems like its bootstrap class problem..Cause when i remove the class it going inside in the div.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution by grabing `bootstrap.min.js` in code behind:

```
 sbTable.Append("<table class='table'>");
            sbTable.Append("<tr><td style='white-space:nowrap'> sample Message td </ td>");
            sbTable.Append("<td> <input name='txtuname' class='form-control' type='text' id='txtuname' runat='server' /> </ td> ");
            sbTable.Append("</ tr>");
            sbTable.Append("</ table>");

            sbTable.Append("<script src = js/bootstrap.min.js ></ script>");
```

Cheers! Hope it helps to anyone.